# How to prevent API calls to be called more than once

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, api

I have an app + website that uses an API where you can purchase goods for virtual currency.

When you've bought an item you can do a refund and get your money back.

Below is some pseudo code to explain.

api/order/refund/{orderid}

```
if(order.status == accepted)
{
    order.status = refunded;
    user.AddMoney(order.Amount);
    dbcontext.saveChanges();
}
```

the problem is, if the API gets called like api/order/refund/21 multiple times quite fast, it will run before saveChanges(); is successful and will AddMoney(); to the user more than once for the same order.

Does anybody know a solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: This may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13404061/how-can-i-lock-a-table-on-read-using-entity-framework You need to lock the table for the duration of your transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing like this:

```
 var vctx = new VenueContext();
        using(var dbtransaction = vctx.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead))
        {
            try
            {
                var order = vctx.Orders.Include("Venue").Include("Transactions.MenuItem").FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == orderid);
                if (order.StatusId != 1)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                if (status == 3 || status == 4)
                {
                    vctx = MoneyRepository.AddMoney(order.UserId, order.Total * -1, vctx);
                }
                order.StatusId = status;
                vctx.SaveChanges();
                dbtransaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                dbtransaction.Rollback();
                return false;
            } 
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a lock like in the sample below

```
private Object thisLock = new Object();
if(order.status == accepted)
{
 lock(thisLock)
{

 if(order.status == accepted)
 {
  order.status = refunded;
  user.AddMoney(order.Amount);
  dbcontext.saveChanges();

 }
}    
}
```

Comment: I used the solution I posted above. Your solution is more simple but I think it would prevent other users from refunding their products at the same time as it locks the statement to only use one thread?

Comment: the lock should wrap the check `order.status == accepted`, otherwise it has no meaning at all. After passing the check, sooner or later the inside code will be executed more than once. When wrapping the check, once the first refunding has been done, the next check will be failed (order.status != accepted) to let execution go inside.

Comment: @Hopeless, thanks made an edit to accommodate that.

-- to que, I do not understand how multiple users can have the same product? My understanding would be that each productId would be uniquely assigned to a user who bought it. please correct my understanding

Comment: @shat90 the scenario here may be that the same user may log in via multiple pages/interfaces/devices ... So it's better to prevent such a case. BTW your edit is still wrong (redundant), we don't need 2 checks `order.status == accepted` (the outer one should be removed)

Comment: I dont want to  lock unless I am sure the order.status is accepted. I put the lock outside the first one, it locks everytime instead of only on the appropriate status, hence not redundant!

Answer (score 0):

I ended using https://github.com/stefanprodan/WebApiThrottle which you can use to limit request amount on selected endpoint.