# Handling concurrency with EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, concurrency

I'm trying to implement storing tree structures in a simple SQL Server database and access them with EntityFramework:

```
Id | Path
----------
1  | '/1/'
2  | '/1/x/'
3  | '/1/x/y/'
4  | '/2/'
5  | '/3/'
```

So, there is one tree with 3 nodes and 2 other trees only consisting of roots. Now, I want to move nodes around, and I came up with the following simple C# function:

```
/// <summary>
/// Move node with all its decendants to new parent
/// </summary>
public static void MoveNode(int nodeToMoveId, int newParentNodeId)
{
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew,new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable }))
    {
        using (var dc = new MyDbContext())
        {
            var nodeToMove = dc.Nodes.Single(x => x.Id == nodeToMoveId);
            var newParentNode = dc.Nodes.Single(x => x.Id == newParentNodeId);
            string oldPath = nodeToMove.Path;
            string newPath = newParentNode.Path + nodeToMove.Name + "/";
            nodeToMove.Path = newPath;
            var subNodesToMove = dc.Nodes.Where(x => x.Path.StartsWith(oldPath)).ToList();
            foreach (var subNodeToMove in subNodesToMove)
            {
                subNodeToMove.Path = subNodeToMove.Path.Replace(oldPath, newPath);
            }

            dc.SaveChanges();
        }
        scope.Complete();
    }
}
```

What I'm concerned about here is concurrency. I used to be under the impression that using `IsolationLevel.Serializable` was going to solve all concurrency issues, but turns out it does not place exclusive read locks onto the data (as explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27846927/1474386)).
So the following situation may occur when 2 threads try simultaneously move one node to different new parent nodes:

```
thread 1: is trying to move node '/1/x/' to new parent '/2/'
thread 2: is trying to move node '/1/x/' to new parent '/3/'
thread 1: oldPath = "1/x"
thread 2: oldPath = "1/x"
thread 1: newPath = "2/x"
thread 1: nodeToMove.Path = "2/x"
thread 1: subNodesToMove = dc.Nodes.Where(x => x.Path.StartsWith("1/x")).ToList() = [ "1/x/y" ]
thread 1: subNodeToMove.Path = "2/x/y"
thread 1: commit transaction
    At this point the hierarchy is the following:
    /1/
    /2/x/
    /2/x/y/
    /2/
    /3/
thread 2: newPath = "3/x"
thread 2: nodeToMove.Path = "3/x"
thread 2: subNodesToMove = dc.Nodes.Where(x => x.Path.StartsWith("1/x")).ToList() = [ ] <-- EMPTY!
thread 2: commit transaction
    At this point the hierarchy is the following:
    /1/
    /3/x/       <- inconsistency
    /2/x/y/     <- here!
    /2/
    /3/
```

The question is: how can I make sure that this kind of race condition never happens in my `MoveNode` method? (note: this code may be executed on different computers simultaneously, so a simple .NET `lock` will not do) I was thinking about using distributed locking mechanisms here, but maybe there is a simpler solution?

Comment: Have you tried with RepeatableRead?