# Update a record from multiple clients at the same time with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

My Data

```
ID   VALUE
1    100
```

I'm using EFCore and Postgresql. I have 2 requests update a record  with `Id =1` in the same time.

- Request 1: Get record `Id = 1`, recieve `{Id =1, Value=100}`, then I update `Value = Value + 10` and update to DB
- Request 2: **When Request 1 don't finish update,** Get record `Id = 1`, recieve `{Id = 1, Value = 100}`, then I update `Value = Value + 20` and update to DB

Finnaly, In DB have `{Id =1, Value= 120}`. I expected `{Id =1, Value= 130}`.

I want when client 2 get data, it must waiting for client finish update that record with new data.

Or when client 2 update data, how can I check data different on DB before Update

Sorry about my English, Thanks for help!

Comment: check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13404061/how-can-i-lock-a-table-on-read-using-entity-framework). It is about the same issue, just different DB server. In short there proposed to lock the record while retrieveing it. Of course there are another ways, to do it in code, e.g. push the action into the single function with thread synchronization in there

Comment: You can also check out Concurrency Tokens or Time Stamp usage in EF Core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/concurrency?tabs=data-annotations. Also there are some docs on how to handle this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency