# Locking table on read in EF Core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, ef-core-3.1

I'm using Entity Framework Core with .NET 6.

I have a function that will auto-generate table primary key of other tables as a id summary and does not consider using `Identity` specification in SQL Server to auto-generate table primary key.

The function's processes are as follows:

1. Get the max id of table
2. Update the newest max id to table
3. Return the primary id

And I'm facing the similar question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13404061/10298544), if my website is using more than one server and there is serveral users create data at once, error might occur (with the conflict of the same ids that returned by function).

I was using T-SQL to fix this problem in Entity Framework with .NET framework 4.6 in the past, the solution just like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22721849/10298544) in the same article above.

But I'm wondering if there is any better solution now in EF Core?
I have searched for [Isolationlevel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.isolationlevel?view=net-6.0) in ef core document, but it seems unable to deal with this situation.

Does anyone have a better solution for this?

Comment: The *better solution* would be to let the database properly handle this - using an `IDENTITY` or a `SEQUENCE` - doing this with a `SELECT MAX(id)+1` approach in code is **flawed** and will most likely result in duplicates - **DON'T DO IT!**

Comment: If you are searching for a more elegant way to lock tables with EF Core than using raw sql, take a look at the package `Thinktecture.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` and the extension method `WithTableHints()`